# Using Haskell Time library ISO8601 format

Tags: haskell, time, dependencies, hackage, haskell-time

I'm using the Haskell Time Library. I'm trying to use the ISO-8601 [date formatters](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/time-1.9.2/docs/Data-Time-Format-ISO8601.html).

In my code, I can import the `Data.Time` module and use it without any problems.
However, when I import the `Data.Time.Format.ISO8601` functions and definitions I get the following error: `Could not find module`.

I'm new to Haskell and I'm not confident in my ability to understand dependencies in the package manager yet. I have a Java oriented background.

Comment: What are the installed packages, what does it print for `cabal freeze`?

Comment: Using cabal freeze returns no dependencies... I guess `my-project.cabal` file is not correctly configured?
I put the time library under the : `executable my-project-exe` part in the `build-depends` section.

Comment: Just to be clear running `cabal freeze` only prints `Resolving dependencies...` and nothing else

Comment: time includes ISO8601 at version 1.9., so you need to figure out if your version number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally manage to understand what was going on thanks to Trevor Cook's comment.

Stack pulls dependencies from Stackage by default, which did not contain the latest time package version. So I needed to specify the version to force stack to use Hackage instead of Stackage for my time package resolution by adding an extra-dep in my `stack.yaml` file:

```
extra-deps:
- time-1.9.2
```

After running `stack build` the compiler was able to find the ISO 8601 Date Format module.

Comment: *stack* pulls dependencies from Stackage by default